# Container that fills up parent container

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, mxml

I have a container whose height can change at runtime. There are some fixed height items at the top and some fixed height items at the bottom, and I would like to have a container between them that fills up the remaining space.

Here's a distilation of the mxml I currently have. I would like the contentContainer to automatically size. compA and compB are mxml components in the real implementation, so their structure (though not necessarily container type) needs to be kept in tact.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" width="100%">
    <mx:VBox width="500" height="500" id="compA">
        <mx:VBox width="100%" id="compB">
            <mx:HBox width="100%">
                <mx:Label text="Header" />
            </mx:HBox>

            <mx:VBox id="contentContainer" width="100%" height="100%">
                <mx:Canvas verticalScrollPolicy="on" width="100%" height="100%">
                    <mx:VBox width="100%" height="100%">
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                        <mx:Label text="Content" />
                    </mx:VBox>
                </mx:Canvas>
            </mx:VBox>
        </mx:VBox>
        <mx:HBox width="100%">
            <mx:Label text="Footer" />
        </mx:HBox>
    </mx:VBox>
</mx:Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can anchor the header and footer to the top and bottom of the screen by setting explicit `height`s on them and specifying `top` and `bottom` parameters.  Then set the main content `VBox`'s `top` and `bottom` parameters to the same values as the header and footer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" width="100%">
    <mx:HBox top="0" height="50">
        <mx:Label text="Header" />
    </mx:HBox>
    <mx:VBox id="contentContainer" width="100%" top="50" bottom="50">
        <mx:Canvas verticalScrollPolicy="on" width="100%" height="100%">
            <mx:VBox width="100%" height="100%">
                <mx:Label text="Content" />
                                    <!-- etc... -->
                <mx:Label text="Content" />
            </mx:VBox>
        </mx:Canvas>
    </mx:VBox>
    <mx:HBox width="100%" bottom="0" height="50">
        <mx:Label text="Footer" />
    </mx:HBox>
</mx:Application>
```

Comment: Aah, top and bottom, obvious in retrospect. Unfortunately in the real application there is a component structure to maintain (I've updated the question to reflect this) and I can't get it to work with that. I expect I just need to change the component's root container type, but I can't figure out what to.

Comment: Can you set a fixed height on the header and footer?  That should work unless you have to keep the fixed dimensions on `compA`